# CC/Javascript Changing stop-color

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to change the value of a stop-color inside an svg via javascript/jquery.

My SVG is external, I've added a classes to my gradient fill.

```
<linearGradient id="paint1_linear" x1="264.64" y1="764.58" x2="264.64" y2="275.06"   
    gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <stop id="gradColor1" class="gradient1" offset="0"/>
   <stop                 class="gradient2" offset="100%"/>
</linearGradient>
```

In CSS I have this thing.

```
:root {
  --color1: blue;
  --color2: #c86dd7;
}

.gradient1 {
  stop-color: var(--color1);
}

.gradient2{
/*  stop-color: var(--color2); */
  stop-color: red;
}
```

Now..I want to change the color of gradient1 via Javascript.

```
gradient1.setProperty("stop-color","green");
```

I have tried a ton of different things but nothing works. 
If my code is correct, then could it be an cross-origin problem with the svg?
Whatever do I need to do?

appreciate any type of clues.

UPDATE: I have tested this, and it works!:

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color1', 'white');
```

So even when this code works, it wont update the color to the external svg, I assume it's a cross-origin problem. If anyone has experience with this let me know.  To sum it up, **How do I change gradients to an external SVG in runtime.**

Comment: Where have you defined `gradient1`?

Comment: Hi, have you tried `gradient1.style.setProperty('--color-stop', "green");` if all solutions you try give you error please add them here. NOTE: gradient1 should be HTML element, use document.getElementById to retrieve it from the DOM.

Comment: Hi, So this works:                                     document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color1', 'white');    I have tested it, works. However as I suspected, it wont update the color on the SVG, Probably because it's a cross-origin problem. I have no idea how to "update" the svg.